# terraform tag value with special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

While trying to update via web console AWS is accepting below tag values, however with terraform its hard to get things done.

The tags that I wanted to update against my resources are:

```
1. "IT R&D & DATA - 7777"
2. "Example Team, Inc. - 001"
```

Getting below error on every different try during terraform apply (However preview always shows correct data). Is there any workaround for this ?

```
Error: error updating LB (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:xxxx:loadbalancer/app/LB-DEV/f4c252) 
  tags: error tagging resource (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:xxxx:loadbalancer/app/LB-DEV/f4c252): 
  ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value 'Example Team, Inc. - 001' at 'tags.1.member.value' 
  failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^([\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}_.:/=+\-@]*)$
```

```
resource "aws_lb" "lb" {

    internal           = "true"
    load_balancer_type = "application"
    name               = format("%s%s","LB-",var.name)
    subnets            = data.aws_subnet_ids.subnet.ids
    security_groups    = [
        data.aws_security_group.sec_group.id
    ]

    tags = {
        business_unit       = "IT R//&D //& DATA //- 7777"
        legal_entity        = replace("Example Team, Inc. - 001", "/(['\\*])/", "//$1")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`&` is not allowed in tags. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tagging.html):

> In general, the allowed characters are letters, numbers, spaces representable in UTF-8, and the following characters: _ . : / = + - @.

Comment: sorry for late reply. even "," also creating problem but if you try from web its not complaining. We are still updating tags with comma to all our resources on the web. But for terraform to work, I removed & and ","